# email receives duplicates from SPRING JAVA Mail APIs

Tags: java, spring, email

I use Java mail APIs from a spring web application to send a weekly email to an outlook mail.
The feature was behaving normally for the first couple of weeks, then without any changes outlook received two emails, the next week three emails were received, then four, then five emails.
The logs set in the Java code indicates that only one email is being sent from the application.
I can't replicate the issue by changing the schedule to send each 15 minutes, or hour, or any shorter interval.

Email controller class

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class WeeklyReportScheduler {

@Autowired
private WeeklyReportService weeklyReportService;

@Scheduled(cron = "${cron.expression}")
public void sendWeeklyReport(){
    weeklyReportService.sendWeeklyReport();
}
}
```

Email service class:

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.mail.MailException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import java.io.*;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class WeeklyReportService {

@Value("${weekly.report.mail.subject}")
private String subject;

@Value("${weekly.report.mail.body}")
private String mailBody;

@Value("${mail.body.empty.report}")
private String emptyReportMailBody;

@Value("${receiver}")
private String receiver;

@Autowired
private MailService mailService;

@Autowired
private WeeklyReportLogDao weeklyReportLogDao;

@Autowired
private ProjectService projectService;

@Value("${export.path}")
private String exportDir;

protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

public void sendWeeklyReport(){
    boolean emptyReport = true;
    //retrieving attachment data 'projects'
    if(projects.size() != 0){
        emptyReport = false;
    }
    String body = "";
    if(emptyReport){
        body = emptyReportMailBody;
    } else {
        body = mailBody;
    }
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/YYYY");
    String dateString = format.format(new Date());
    String mailSubject = subject + " " + dateString;
    List recipients = new ArrayList<String>();
    recipients.add(receiver);
    String fileName = mailSubject.replace(" ", "_").replace("/", "_");
    WeeklyReportExcelExport excelExport = new WeeklyReportExcelExport(exportDir, fileName);
    excelExport.createReport(projects);
    File excelFile = excelExport.saveToFile();
    File[] attachments = new File[1];
    attachments[0] = excelFile;

    boolean sent = false;
    String exceptionMessage = "";
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        try {
            logger.info("Sending Attempt: " + i+1);
            Thread.sleep(10000);
            mailService.mail(recipients, mailSubject, body, attachments);
            sent = true;
            break;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            logger.info("sending failed because: " + ex.getMessage() + " \nRe-attempting in 10 seconds");
            exceptionMessage = ex.getMessage();
            sent = false;
        }
    }
    if(!sent){
        weeklyReportLogDao.logFailedReporting(dateString, exceptionMessage);
    }
    //re-try 3 times in case of mail sending failure
}
```

MailService class:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.springframework.mail.MailException;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSender;
import org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper;

public class MailServiceImpl implements MailService {

/** The From address for the e-mail. read from ant build properties file */
private String fromAddress;

/** The mail sender. */
private JavaMailSender mailSender;

/** Logger for this class and subclasses */
protected final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

public void mail(List<String> emailAddresses, String subject, String text, File[] attachments) throws MailException {
   //System.out.println("mail: "+subject);
    MimeMessage message = null;

    // Fill in the From, To, and Subject fields.
    try {
        message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();

        MimeMessageHelper messageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
        messageHelper.setFrom(fromAddress);
        for (String emailAddress : emailAddresses) {
            messageHelper.addTo(emailAddress);
        }
        messageHelper.setSubject(subject);

        // Fill in the body with the message text, sending it in HTML format.
        messageHelper.setText(text, true);

        // Add any attachments to the message.
        if ((attachments != null) && (attachments.length != 0)) {
            for (File attachment : attachments) {
                messageHelper.addAttachment(attachment.getName(), attachment);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(MessagingException mse) {
        String warnMessage = "Error creating message.";
        logger.warn(warnMessage);
        throw (new RuntimeException(warnMessage, mse));
    }
    try {
        mailSender.send(message);
    } catch (Exception ex){
        logger.info("Exception sending message: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

you might have duplicate entries on your argument emailAddresses, try moving it to treeset if you cant ensure duplicate entries from the repository layer